# Test case fails for custom exception flutter mockito

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, testing, mockito

I write a calculator service test case, by mocking calculator object using mockito

This is my test cases

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';

import 'calculator_service.dart';
import 'data.dart';
import 'data.mocks.dart';

void main() {
  /// Group for calculator service
  group('Calculator Service', () {
    MockCalculator mockCalculator = MockCalculator();
    late CalculatorService service;
    setUp(() {
      service = CalculatorService(mockCalculator);
    });

    test('test addition of two numbers', () {
      when(service.sumOfTwoNumbers(5, 5))
          .thenAnswer((Invocation realInvocation) => 10);

      expect(service.sumOfTwoNumbers(5, 5), 10);
    });

    test('test multiplication of two numbers', () {
      when(service.multiplyOfTwoNumbers(5, 5))
          .thenAnswer((Invocation realInvocation) => 25);

      int res = service.multiplyOfTwoNumbers(5, 5);

      expect(res, 25);
    });

    test('test division of two numbers', () {
      when(service.divideOfTwoNumbers(5, 5))
          .thenAnswer((Invocation realInvocation) => 1);

      double res = service.divideOfTwoNumbers(5, 5);

      expect(res, 1);
    });

    test('test division of two numbers throws exception', () {
      when(service.divideOfTwoNumbers(5, 0))
          .thenThrow(InfinityException('Denominator cannot be zero'));
      expect(
          service.divideOfTwoNumbers(5, 0), throwsA(isA<InfinityException>()));
    });
  });
}
```

CalculatorService

```
import 'data.dart';

class CalculatorService {
  Calculator calc;

  CalculatorService(this.calc);

  int sumOfTwoNumbers(int x, int y) {
    int res = calc.sum(x, y);
    return res;
  }

  int multiplyOfTwoNumbers(int x, int y) {
    int res = calc.multiply(x, y);
    return res;
  }

  double divideOfTwoNumbers(int x, int y) {
    double res = 0;
    if (y == 0) {
      throw InfinityException('Denominator Cannot be Zero');
    } else {
      res = calc.divide(x, y);
    }
    return res;
  }
}
```

Calculator

```
import 'package:mockito/annotations.dart';

@GenerateMocks([Calculator])
class Calculator {
  ///
  int multiply(int x, int y) {
    return x * y;
  }

  int sum(int x, int y) => x + y;

  double divide(int numerator, int denominator) {
    if (denominator != 0) {
      return numerator / denominator;
    } else {
      throw InfinityException('Denominator cannot be zero!!');
    }
  }
}

class InfinityException implements Exception {
  String message;

  InfinityException(this.message);
}
```

I get this error for the **`test division of two numbers throws exception`** test case

```
test/calculator_service.dart 24:7  CalculatorService.divideOfTwoNumbers
test/sample_test.dart 43:20        main.<fn>.<fn>

Instance of 'InfinityException'
```